# CodeIgniter controller can't load database

Tags: php, codeigniter

I created a controller in CodeIgniter which controlls the whole admin. It's load another controller if neccessary, depend on the URL. It's works correctly, but the controllers which is loaded by the Admin controller, these can't reach the database.

Here is my code in the Admin controller which load the neccessary controller.

```
public function renderAdmin(){
    $get=$this->input->get();
    if (!empty($get['module'])){
        $module=$get['module'];
    }
    else{
        $module="";
    }
    if (!empty($module)){
        if (!empty($get['method'])){
            $method=$get['method'];
        }
        else{
            $method="index";
        }
        $module=modules::load($module."/".$module);
        if (!method_exists($module, $method)){
            $method="index";
        }
        $module->$method();
    }
    else{
        $data['screen']=$this->config->item('foo_template_dir_admin')."index";
        $data['menuPoints']=self::getMenuPoints();
        $this->load->view($this->config->item('foo_template_dir_admin') . "frame", $data);
    }
}
```

And when I load e.g. the tags controller, it's can't load the database.

```
public function index(){
    $data['menuPoints']=Admin::getMenuPoints();
    $data['screen']=$this->config->item('mindenrekepes_template_dir_admin')."tags/index";

    var_dump($this->db); // NULL

    $this->load->view($this->config->item('mindenrekepes_template_dir_admin')."frame", $data);
}
```

The database is in the autoloading file, so it's would be loaded.

In the Admin controller or in one of it's models, I can reach the database, so the database config and the autoloading is also right int the main controller.

Do you know would be the problem? I hope somebody can help me out in this case.

Comment: This is in the autoload and work correctly, but only the main controller has the $db attribute and the others not.

Comment: I found the problem, because the HMVC extension I would extend MX_Controller instead of MY_Controller. Sorry, I didn't mention in the question how I use HMVC. But I accept the answer of @g9m29 because that was really helpfull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can further improve your app logic design because I don't think this is optimal. For your needs, though you can try using this method.

```
private static $db;
  function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    self::$db = &get_instance()->db;
  }
```

Try adding the private static $db variable to your controller and create a DB instance in the __construct. Then you can continue using your db like `self::db->get()->result()-> etc.`

Comment: I would add this in every controller which is loaded by the main controller?

Comment: It's not worked, I still got null in every controller for the $db property.

Comment: Yes in every controller that exist apart from your controllers but have the ability to utilize all of CI's resources. If those controllers are called from within CI and are "common" controllers for CI and extend the main CI_Controller or MY_Controller, then please provide your main controller and one sub-controller with whole code, so we can see where the coupling is wrong.

Comment: #g9m29 answered right you need to load parent constructor or check whether code igniter instance created or not

Answer (score 0):

Try this in constructor:

```
function __construct(){
 $this->load->database();
}
```